# Isomorphism of complements in semi-direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with normal subgroups $M,N$ and subgroups $H,K$ such that $M \cong N$, $MH=NK=G$, and $M \cap H = N \cap K = 1$. Is it the case that $H \cong K$?

Clearly $H \cong G/M$ and $K \cong G/N$, so this is similar to [Isomorphic quotient groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40763/isomorphic-quotient-groups/) but of course the examples there are not semi-direct products.

I assumed counterexamples would be plentiful, <s>but unless I made a mistake, there are no examples with |G| ≤ 300.</s>

This question was motivated by Tobias's remarks in his question [How to determine if two semidirect products are isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405712/how-to-determine-if-two-semidirect-products-are-isomorphic)

Comment: Isn't $C_3 \times D_6$ (order 18), with normal subgroups of order 3 and quotients $C_6$ and $D_6$ a counterexample? Or have I missed a condition?

Comment: @DerekHolt: that looks good! Just a code error. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it up, and why this is obviously the thing to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just Derek Holt's answer (CW):

Let $G=C_3 \times S_3$ with normal subgroups $M=C_3 \times 1$ and $N=1 \times A_3$ and complements $H=1 \times S_3$ and $K=C_3 \times S_2$. Then $M,N$ are normal and isomorphic. $M \cap H = N \cap K = 1$ is clear, and then $MH=NK=G$ follows automatically from order considerations.

This is the unique smallest order example, and obviously generalizes to $C_p \times D_{2p}$.

In general, $$\begin{array}{rcl}
G&=&(A \rtimes B) \times (A \rtimes C) \\
M&=&(A \rtimes 1) \times (1 \rtimes 1) \\
N&=&(1 \rtimes 1) \times (A \rtimes 1) \\
H&=&(1 \rtimes B) \times (A \rtimes C) \\
K&=&(A \rtimes B) \times (1 \rtimes C)
\end{array}$$
is sort of the obvious thing to try, and it in fact usually works. For instance if $B$, $C$, $A \rtimes B$, and $A \rtimes C$ are all directly indecomposable, then $H \not\cong K$ as long as $B \not\cong C$. For instance Derek took $B=1$, $A=C_3$, and $C=C_2$.