# Show a group of order 182 is solvable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I was looking at this thread and it doesn't quite answer my question.

[Classify all groups of order 182](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405040/classify-all-groups-of-order-182)

Also, I am using Lang's Algebra. So far we have only covered the first 7 chapters.

Here is what I have.

Let $G$ be a group of order 182. Since $182=2\cdot7\cdot13,$ sylow's theorems guarantee the existence of p-sylow subgroups denoted by $H_2,H_7,H_{13}$ respectively. Again, by Sylow, we have that the number of sylow-7 subgroups, denoted by $n_7$, is 1 since $n_1\equiv1\mod7$ and $n_7\mid26$. Since $n_7=1$ and all p-sylow subgroups are conjugate, we get that $H_7$ is unique and thus for any $g\in G$ we have $gH_7g^{-1}=H_7$. Therefore, $H_7\lhd G$. Thus, $G/H_7$ is a group or order 26 and is isomorphic to a subgroup $A<G$. Since $A$ has order $26=2\cdot13$, it has order equal to the product of two distinct primes, and is therefore solvable. Since $G/A$ has order 7, it is cyclic, which means it is abelian, and thus it is solvable. Therefore, since $A$ and $G/A$ are solvable, $G$ is solvable.

My issue is, I just found out that if $H\lhd G$, then $G/H\cong K$ for some $K<G$ is not always true. That statement is true for abelian groups, but we don't have the assumption that $G$ is abelian. Is there a way to salvage this, or am I going about it in the wrong way?

Comment: All groups of order $182$ are soluble.

Comment: You don't need $A$ to be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.  You have $H_7$, and normal cyclic (order $7$) subgroup of $G$ is solvable, and by your argument, $G/H_7$ is solvable, so $G$ is solvable.

Comment: For clarification, you are saying that even though $G/H_7$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$, it is still solvable because of its order. Thus, look at $G/(G/H_7)$ which is a group of order 7 so it is solvable. Therefore, $G$ is solvable? Is this right? How do you know that $G/H_7\lhd G$ if it may not even be a subgroup of $G$

Comment: @JohnC No. You've argued that $H_7$ is normal in $G$, and that $G/H_7$ is solvable. But $H_7$ itself is solvable (it is cyclic!).  So you have that $G$ is solvable-by-solvable, hence, itself solvable.

Comment: Got it. The theorem I'm looking at doesn't mention that $G/H_7$ has to be a subgroup, but I believe I was thinking of the actual definition involving abelian towers and kept trying to put the quotient in the tower for whatever reason.

Comment: The title of this question says the opposite of what you mean, so you should correct it.

Answer (score 2):

So, in short, as $P\in Syl_7(G)$ and we have $P\unlhd G$ by divisibility condition on the no. of Sylow $7$-subgroups of $G$, we obtain our quotient group $G/P$, of order $2\times 13$. By Burnside, the quotient is solvable. Both $P$ and $G/P$ are solvable imply $G$ is solvable.